# How to recalculate IP checksum in netfilter?

Tags: c++, linux, module, kernel, netfilter

I'm developing a netfilter kernel module in which I need to recalculate IP checksum. I used this function to calculate IP checksum (found it somewhere on internet):

```
unsigned short ComputeIPChecksum(unsigned char *data, int len)
{
         long sum = 0;  /* assume 32 bit long, 16 bit short */
     unsigned short *temp = (unsigned short *)data;

         while(len > 1){
             sum += *temp++;
             if(sum & 0x80000000)   /* if high order bit set, fold */
               sum = (sum & 0xFFFF) + (sum >> 16);
             len -= 2;
         }

         if(len)       /* take care of left over byte */
             sum += (unsigned short) *((unsigned char *)temp);

         while(sum>>16)
             sum = (sum & 0xFFFF) + (sum >> 16);

        return ~sum;
}
```

By looking in wireshark I can see that incoming packets are received successfully but for outgoing packets wireshark show incorrect ip checksum.
Here's my hook function:

```
static unsigned int hook_func(unsigned int hooknum,
                        struct sk_buff *skb,
                                const struct net_device *in,
                                const struct net_device *out,
                                int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *))
{
    sock_buff = skb; 

    if (sock_buff)
    {
            ip_header = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(sock_buff);
            if (ip_header && ip_header->protocol == TCP)
            {
                ip_header->check = ComputeIPChecksum((unsigned char *)ip_header, ip_header->ihl*4);
            }
    }
    return NF_ACCEPT;
}
```

And here is the main, I''ve binded same hook function to PRE_ROUTING and POST_ROUTING

```
static int __init init_main(void)
{
    nfho.hook     = hook_func;
    nfho.hooknum  = 0;
    nfho.pf       = PF_INET;
    nfho.priority = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;

    nfho1.hook     = hook_func;
    nfho1.hooknum  = 4;
    nfho1.pf       = PF_INET;
    nfho1.priority = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;

    nf_register_hook(&nfho);
    nf_register_hook(&nfho1);

    return 0;
}
```

Why is the IP checksum get corrupted for outgoing packets???

The error shown in wireshark:

```
Header checksum: 0x0000 [incorrect, should be 0x85de (maybe caused by "IP checksum offload"?)]
```

Comment: You're implementing a Linux kernel module in C++?

Comment: You're using code "you found on the internet", in a Linux kernel module? Do you understand what copyright means? Do you understand that "signed-off-by" means you swear you wrote all the code or that the person who owns the copyright to the code has licensed it under GPLv2?

Comment: Define "corrupt IP header". Does that mean "incorrect checksum" or actually "corrupt IP header"? If the latter, then you're probably messing up something else.

Comment: Header checksum: 0x0000 [incorrect, should be 0x85de (maybe caused by "IP checksum offload"?)]

Answer (score 1):

Where are you capturing packets?

IP checksums (as well as TCP/UDP checksums) can be calculated by the network card itself. If this is the case on your card (and it's a very common feature) and you are capturing on your machine I'd expect to see 0 checksums.

Answer (score 1):

If you defined the IP header like this:

```
struct iphdr *iph;
```

and then

```
iph = (struct iphdr *) skb_header_pointer(skb, 0, 0, NULL);
```

then you can recalculate the checksum just like the following.

```
/* Calculation of IP header checksum */
iph->check = 0;
ip_send_check (iph);
```

You may have a look at my question: [How to append data on a packet from kernel space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529497/how-to-append-data-on-a-packet-from-kernel-space/12841411#12841411)
There you can find detail code at the given answer by myself at the bottom. There I had to
recalculate the IP and UDP header checksum.